# Published C# Console App - The system cannot find the file specificied

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, clickonce

I am using a very short C# console app to launch an executable written in python, so that I can take advantage of click-once deployment.

In debug mode I am able to locate the two executable files that are included as resources. However, once the App is published I cannot seem to locate their relative file paths. I get an exception: "system cannot find the file specified"

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace UpdateConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string RunningPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            string driver_path = string.Format("{0}Resources\\chromedriver.exe", System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(RunningPath, @"")));
            string exe_path  = string.Format("{0}Resources\\DUU.exe", System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(RunningPath, @"")));

            Process.Start(exe_path,driver_path);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried to reference the resource like so:

```
Properties.Resources.DUU;
```

But this returns a byte[] object and I am not sure how to extract a relative file path from here.

Comment: Your OS doesn't know anything about .NET resources, or byte[], it *requires* a file on disk.

Comment: `var driver_path = Path.Combine(RunningPath, @"Resources\chromedriver.exe"")`. Also make sure you're copying the file to the specificed location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 string RunningPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

the file path provided by this code changes based on the build mode:
1. In debug mode it is .../bin/Debug.
2. In release mode it is .../bin/Release.

So make sure you copy the .exe files to the appropriate folder.